# useContext passing wrong props

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-context

I have my context Provider in my `AppContext.tsx` file

```
import { useState, useEffect, useContext, createContext } from 'react';

interface AppContextProps {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

const themes = {
  dark: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    color: 'white'
  },
  light: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    color: 'black'
  }
}

const initialState = {
  dark: false,
  theme: themes.light,
  toggle: () => { console.log('toggle from initalState') }
}

const AppContext = createContext(initialState);

export function AppWrapper({ children }: AppContextProps) {
  const [dark, setDark] = useState(false) // Default theme is light

  // On mount, read the preferred theme from the persistence
  useEffect(() => {
    const isDark = localStorage.getItem('dark') === 'true'
    setDark(isDark)
  }, [dark])

  // To toggle between dark and light modes
  const toggle = () => {
    console.log('toggle from AppWrapper')
    const isDark = !dark
    localStorage.setItem('dark', JSON.stringify(isDark))
    setDark(isDark)
  }

  const theme = dark ? themes.dark : themes.light

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ theme, dark, toggle }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useAppContext() {
  return useContext(AppContext);
}
```

I insert `Appwrapper` into my `_app.tsx` file

```
import type { ReactElement, ReactNode } from 'react'
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { AppWrapper } from '../contexts/AppContext';
import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';
import '../styles/globals.scss'

type NextPageWithLayout = NextPage & {
  getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode
}

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout
}

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) => {
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page)
  return getLayout(
    <AppWrapper>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </AppWrapper>
  )
}

export default App
```

And I call and import the `useAppContext` hook to use it in my `Header` component

```
import styles from './header.module.scss'
import { useAppContext } from '../contexts/AppContext'

const Header = () => {
  const { theme, toggle, dark } = useAppContext()

  return (
    <header className={styles.header}>
      <nav className={styles.nav}>
        <div onClick={toggle} className={styles.switchWrap}>
          <label className={styles.switch}>
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span className={styles.slider}></span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

However, my `toggle` function logs `toggle from initalState` instead of `toggle from AppWrapper`.

The following code below

```
const { theme, toggle, dark } = useAppContext()
```

gets data from `initialState`

```
const initialState = {
  dark: false,
  theme: themes.light,
  toggle: () => { console.log('toggle from initalState') }
}
```

instead of what I pass into the `value` props shown below

```
<AppContext.Provider value={{ theme, dark, toggle }}>
  {children}
</AppContext.Provider>
```

How do I correctly pass the `value` props data into my component instead of the data from `initialState`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because my app was using per-page layouts, I inserted `AppWrapper` in my layout file instead of `_app.tsx` and everything works

```
import Header from './header'
import Footer from './footer'
import { AppWrapper } from '../contexts/AppContext';

interface LayoutProps {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

const Layout = ({ children }: LayoutProps) => {
  return (
    <AppWrapper>
      <Header />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </AppWrapper>
  )
}

export const getLayout = (page: LayoutProps) => <Layout>{page}</Layout>;

export default Layout
```